# Python: Parallelized image reading and preprocessing using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, machine-learning, computer-vision, multiprocessing

For a machine learning application, I am trying to write an image reader class in python that reads in images, preprocesses them and passes them to the application in batches.

The reading and preprocessing needs to happen in parallel to the machine learning training/testing, which was easy to achieve using threading and a queue. However, since the preprocessing is computationally expensive, I would like to parallelize it further, such that individual images are read and preprocessed in parallel in different processes. I tried to achieve this in the following way (note that the example is stripped of everything that is irrelevant to the problem, e.g. the reading of the labels)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import csv
from multiprocessing import Queue, Pool

def load_image(fname):
    return cv2.imread(fname)[:,:,[2,1,0]].astype(np.float32)

class ImageReader(object):

    def __init__(self, path_to_csv, batchsize, transform=None):

        self.path_to_csv = path_to_csv
        self.batchsize = batchsize
        self.transform = transform

        self.fnames = []
        csvfile = open(path_to_csv, 'rb')
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            self.fnames.append(row[0])

        self.num_samples = len(self.fnames)

    def __iter__(self):

        q = Queue(maxsize=3*self.batchsize)
        def producer(fname):
            if self.transform is None:
                q.put(load_image(fname))
            else:
                q.put(self.transform(load_image(fname)))
        p = Pool()
        p.map(producer, self.fnames)

        for i in range(self.num_samples//self.batchsize):
            Xlst = []
            for j in range(self.batchsize):
                Xlst.append(q.get())
            yield np.array(Xlst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = ImageReader('some_path', 128, transform=None)
    for Xb in r:
        print Xb.shape
```

The important part is

```
    q = Queue(maxsize=3*self.batchsize)
    def producer(fname):
        if self.transform is None:
            q.put(load_image(fname))
        else:
            q.put(self.transform(load_image(fname)))
    p = Pool()
    p.map(producer, self.fnames)
```

where I want a pool of workers to process images (specified in a list of filenames) in parallel and put them in a queue that is later accessed.

This fails due to the fact that `producer` is defined inside the class and, hence, can not be pickled. There are a couple of workarounds floating around stackoverflow, that make functions pickleable, but none of them seems to work in my special case, where `producer` puts items in a queue. Does anybody have an idea for my specific situation?

Also: do I have the right approach apart from the problem with pickleability? I am not quite sure since this is the first time I am using multiprocessing.

Comment: Note that `range(self.num_samples//self.batchsize)` will be `range(0)` for say `num_samples=1` and `batchsize=16`, hence the loop will do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using joblib? e.g.

```
from scipy.misc import imread, imsave
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed

def read_images(image_paths_list):
    images = Parallel(n_jobs=4, verbose=5)(
        delayed(imread)(f) for f in image_paths_list
    )
    return images
```

That could read a batch of images in parallel, then a similar pattern could be used to post-process them?